# Python/Pandas Select Columns based on Best Value Distribution

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a dataframe (df) in pandas/python with ['Product','OrderDate','Sales'].
I noticed that some rows, values have better Distribution (like in a Histogram) than others. By "Best" meaning, the shape is more spread, or the spread of values make the shape looks wider than for other rows.

If I want to pick from say +700 Product's, those with more spread values, is there a way to do that easily in pandas/python?

txs in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for greater standard deviation/variance or that the values as a whole fit a normal distribution better?

Comment: Hi EdChum. I'm looking for the values as a whole fit a normal distribution, or as close as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat here is that I'm not a stats expert but basically scipy has a number of tests you can conduct on your data to test whether it could be considered to be a normalised Gaussian distribution.

Here I create 2 series one is simple a linear range and the other is a random normalised sampling with mean set to 50 and variance set to 25.

```
In [48]:

import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
df = pd.DataFrame({'linear':arange(100), 'normal':np.random.normal(50, 25, 100)})
df
Out[48]:
    linear      normal
0        0   66.565374
1        1   63.453899
2        2   65.736406
3        3   65.848908
4        4   56.916032
5        5   93.870682
6        6   89.513998
7        7    9.949555
8        8    9.727099
9        9   47.072785
10      10   62.849321
11      11   33.263309
12      12   42.168484
13      13   38.488933
14      14   51.833459
15      15   54.911915
16      16   62.372709
17      17   96.928452
18      18   65.333546
19      19   26.341462
20      20   41.692790
21      21   22.852561
22      22   15.799415
23      23   50.600141
24      24   14.234088
25      25   72.428607
26      26   45.872601
27      27   80.783253
28      28   29.561586
29      29   51.261099
..     ...         ...
70      70   32.826052
71      71   35.413106
72      72   49.415386
73      73   28.998378
74      74   32.237667
75      75   86.622402
76      76  105.098296
77      77   53.176413
78      78   -7.954881
79      79   60.313761
80      80   42.739641
81      81   56.667834
82      82   68.046688
83      83   72.189683
84      84   67.125708
85      85   24.798553
86      86   58.845761
87      87   54.559792
88      88   93.116777
89      89   30.209895
90      90   80.952444
91      91   57.895433
92      92   47.392336
93      93   13.136111
94      94   26.624532
95      95   53.461421
96      96   28.782809
97      97   16.342756
98      98   64.768579
99      99   68.410021

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

From this [page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#special-tests-for-normal-distributions) there are a number of tests we can use which are combined to for the `normaltest`, namely the `skewtest` and `kurtosistest`, I cannot explain these but you can see that the p-value is poor for the linear series and is relatively closer to 1 for the normalised data:

```
In [49]:

print('linear skewtest teststat = %6.3f pvalue = %6.4f' % sc.stats.skewtest(df['linear']))
print('normal skewtest teststat = %6.3f pvalue = %6.4f' % sc.stats.skewtest(df['normal']))

print('linear kurtoisis teststat = %6.3f pvalue = %6.4f' % sc.stats.kurtosistest(df['linear']))
print('normal kurtoisis teststat = %6.3f pvalue = %6.4f' % sc.stats.kurtosistest(df['normal']))

print('linear normaltest teststat = %6.3f pvalue = %6.4f' % sc.stats.normaltest(df['linear']))
print('normal normaltest teststat = %6.3f pvalue = %6.4f' % sc.stats.normaltest(df['normal']))
linear skewtest teststat =  1.022 pvalue = 0.3070
normal skewtest teststat = -0.170 pvalue = 0.8652
linear kurtoisis teststat = -5.799 pvalue = 0.0000
normal kurtoisis teststat = -1.113 pvalue = 0.2656
linear normaltest teststat = 34.674 pvalue = 0.0000
normal normaltest teststat =  1.268 pvalue = 0.5304
```

From the `scipy` site:

> When testing for normality of a small sample of t-distributed
>   observations and a large sample of normal distributed observation,
>   then in neither case can we reject the null hypothesis that the sample
>   comes from a normal distribution. In the first case this is because
>   the test is not powerful enough to distinguish a t and a normally
>   distributed random variable in a small sample.

So you'll have to try the above and see if it fits with what you want, hope this helps.

Comment: this is what I as looking for. Txs v-much EdChum. I as starting to think of applying a Machine Learning Classifier to get the best Gaussian Shapped rows but I think with this idea of yours, the main subject is covered.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. What you'd like to do here is find the 700 entries with the largest standard deviation.

`pandas.DataFrame.std()` will return the standard deviation for an axis, and then you just need to keep track of the entries with the highest corresponding values.

[Large Standard Deviation vs. Small Standard Deviation](http://www.thepokerbank.com/images/std-dev-low-high.png)